# Java cast exception keeps randomly appearing(first it can cast, after it cant)

Tags: java, casting, classcastexception

```
protected List query(String condition) {

    String queryString = "FROM Worker";
    System.out.println("adding to query");
    if (condition != null) {
        queryString += " " + condition;
        System.out.println(condition);
    }
    System.out.println("added to query");
    Query query = em().createQuery(queryString);
    System.out.println("created query");

    System.out.println("starting query");
    List < Radnik > c = query.getResultList();

    System.out.println(c.size());

    List < WorkerBean > result = new ArrayList < WorkerBean > ();
    System.out.println("before for");
    if (c instanceof List <? > ) {
        System.out.println("YES!");
        for (Object obj: c) {
            System.out.println("entered!!!");
            System.out.println(c.get(0).getClass());
            if (obj instanceof Worker) {
                System.out.println("it's a worker");
            }
            Workerentity = (Worker) obj;
            result.add(EntityToBean(entity));
        }
        c.clear();
        System.out.println("out of for");

    }

    return result;
}
```

So the thing that's bugging me and all of the others in the office is that on first call of this query it goes through without a problem(full list of workers), but when I called for the second time(with some parameters) it says that the list size is as I expected but throws a

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to.
```

So to sum up it can't cast for the second time (@System.out.println(c.get(0).getClass());

Comment: No need for `if( c instanceof List<?>){`, since this is ensured by API.

Comment: instead of `System.out.println(c.get(0).getClass());` didn't you want to print `System.out.println(o.getClass());`. I'm sure that on the second call the data (list) will not be the same.

Comment: How is Worker related to Radnik?

Comment: What are your "some parameters" that you pass when it goes wrong? That is most probably the key to your problem as it is the difference between the query that works and the one that doesn't work. Please put this information in your question.

Comment: Most likely your condition is adding another alias that will be returned from the query (the result becomes of type `Object[]` instead of `Worker`). The solution is to put `SELECT` before the `FROM` to identify what you want to return from the query:  `SELECT x FROM Worker x`

Comment: @VictorSorokin I know, it's just for checking

Comment: @StijnGeukens still doesn't work and Worker and Radnik are the same(translating from Serbian)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the SELECT part is done separetly... So the first call is to fill all the workers to a list(with casting and everything) and it works fine, second time when I want to get all managers(my query is good because the list size is as expected) list elements can not be casted...I know it's really stupid, but it's also really frustrating, I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysterious ClassCastExceptions tend to happen when you ignore compiler warnings related to generics.  Turn on all compiler warnings, and make sure you address them.  In particular, do not use raw types (such as `List` with no generic type), and do not call methods which use or return raw types.

By using generics properly, your method can shortened to this:

```
protected List<WorkerBean> query(String condition) {

    String queryString = "FROM Worker";
    System.out.println("adding to query");
    if (condition != null) {
        queryString += " " + condition;
        System.out.println(condition);
    }
    System.out.println("added to query");

    TypedQuery<Radnik> query = em().createQuery(queryString, Radnik.class);
    System.out.println("created query");

    System.out.println("starting query");
    List < Radnik > c = query.getResultList();

    System.out.println(c.size());

    List < WorkerBean > result = new ArrayList < WorkerBean > ();
    for (Radnik obj: c) {
        result.add(EntityToBean(obj));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Notice the use of [TypedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TypedQuery.html) instead of Query.

As long as your code generates no compiler warnings, generically typed Lists are guaranteed to contain the correct type of object, so there is no need to check the validity of your result list.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like a decent answer, but the project that I'm on doesn't work like that so no TypedQuery for me, but definitely a correct answer...

Answer (score 0):

Consider paying attention to details.

```
 if (obj instanceof Worker) {
     System.out.println("it's a worker");
 }

 Workerentity = (Worker) obj;
```

The attempt to cast the obj to a Worker happens irrespective of obj being an instance of Worker.

move the cast inside the if statement block.

Comment: Although it prints It's a worker, even if the cast is inside of if I throws the exception

Comment: add an else to print when it is not a worker and you will be amazed to find that you are attempting to cast a non worker to a worker.

Answer (score 0):

So after coming again after a day, and restarting everything for a couple of times(that desperate I was). It's all working now. It's not the first time this happened to me(probably some garbage collector etc.) 
Thank you for the efforts guys :)

Comment: Don't blame poor GC...

Comment: I'm sorry GC i was wrong and I'm a bad person!

Answer (score 0):

So to update, I was having a List of Objects because it wasn't specifically said what should I select, and the FROM part had multiple tables! :dummy